# values for find criteria and find control in soap ui

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

below is xml soapui version of a wsdl obtained from oracle oer to get salary details from fusion.The webservice asks for **Assignmentid**,**hiredate**,**findcriteria**,**findcontrol**,When i consume this webservice in **Jdeveloper** i give find creiteria and findcontrol as null and pass values to assignmentid and hiredate and i am able to get salary attribute .But problem with soap ui is i dono what to pass it for find criteria and find control .My task is to run it in soapui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/hcm/compensation/salary/core/salaryServiceV2/types/" xmlns:typ1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:findSalaryfindByAssignmentIdAndDate>
         <typ:findCriteria>
            <typ1:fetchStart>0</typ1:fetchStart>
            <typ1:fetchSize>-1</typ1:fetchSize>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <typ1:filter>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <typ1:conjunction>?</typ1:conjunction>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <typ1:group>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <typ1:conjunction>?</typ1:conjunction>
                  <typ1:upperCaseCompare>false</typ1:upperCaseCompare>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <typ1:item>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <typ1:conjunction>?</typ1:conjunction>
                     <typ1:upperCaseCompare>false</typ1:upperCaseCompare>
                     <typ1:attribute>?</typ1:attribute>
                     <typ1:operator>?</typ1:operator>
                     <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <typ1:value>?</typ1:value>
                     <typ1:nested />
                  </typ1:item>
               </typ1:group>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <typ1:nested />
            </typ1:filter>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <typ1:sortOrder>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <typ1:sortAttribute>
                  <typ1:name>?</typ1:name>
                  <typ1:descending>false</typ1:descending>
               </typ1:sortAttribute>
            </typ1:sortOrder>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <typ1:findAttribute>?</typ1:findAttribute>
            <typ1:excludeAttribute>false</typ1:excludeAttribute>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <typ1:childFindCriteria>
               <typ1:fetchStart>0</typ1:fetchStart>
               <typ1:fetchSize>-1</typ1:fetchSize>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <typ1:filter>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <typ1:conjunction>?</typ1:conjunction>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <typ1:group>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <typ1:conjunction>?</typ1:conjunction>
                     <typ1:upperCaseCompare>false</typ1:upperCaseCompare>
                     <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                     <typ1:item>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <typ1:conjunction>?</typ1:conjunction>
                        <typ1:upperCaseCompare>false</typ1:upperCaseCompare>
                        <typ1:attribute>?</typ1:attribute>
                        <typ1:operator>?</typ1:operator>
                        <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                        <typ1:value>?</typ1:value>
                        <typ1:nested />
                     </typ1:item>
                  </typ1:group>
                  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                  <typ1:nested />
               </typ1:filter>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <typ1:sortOrder>
                  <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
                  <typ1:sortAttribute>
                     <typ1:name>?</typ1:name>
                     <typ1:descending>false</typ1:descending>
                  </typ1:sortAttribute>
               </typ1:sortOrder>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <typ1:findAttribute>?</typ1:findAttribute>
               <typ1:excludeAttribute>false</typ1:excludeAttribute>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <typ1:childFindCriteria />
               <typ1:childAttrName>?</typ1:childAttrName>
            </typ1:childFindCriteria>
         </typ:findCriteria>
         <typ:assignmentId>?</typ:assignmentId>
         <typ:effectiveDate>?</typ:effectiveDate>
         <typ:findControl>
            <typ1:retrieveAllTranslations>false</typ1:retrieveAllTranslations>
         </typ:findControl>
      </typ:findSalaryfindByAssignmentIdAndDate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a node with null value, you can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/hcm/compensation/salary/core/salaryServiceV2/types/"
    xmlns:typ1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:findSalaryfindByAssignmentIdAndDate>
         <typ:findCriteria /><!-- NULLed node -->
         <typ:assignmentId>your_id</typ:assignmentId>
         <typ:effectiveDate>effective_date</typ:effectiveDate>
         <typ:findControl /><!-- NULLed node -->
      </typ:findSalaryfindByAssignmentIdAndDate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```